# Unrecognized attribute ‘targetframework’ when debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Although there are several questions and answers about the "Unrecognized attribute ‘targetframework’" error, the other questions mainly have to do with errors  deploying to a server, and so the answers show IIS 7 settings that need changing.  In my case, I was getting the "Unrecognized attribute ‘targetframework’" error when trying to debug in Visual Studio.

I manually modified my web.config file to upgrade it to 4.0, as described in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx).  That included adding the targetFramework attribute to my compilation tag, like this:

```
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

I did this because I wanted to use an assembly that targeted the 4.0 framework.  But then when I tried to debug the site, I received the "Unrecognized attribute ‘targetframework’" error.  As I mentioned, the solutions that I found all talked about changing the application pool in IIS 7, but I was just trying to run the site in the Visual Studio debugger.  I tried looking at the Properties for the Solution, but didn't find anything about the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a lot longer than it should have, but eventually I found the other Properties dialog I was looking for.  It wasn't in the Solution Properties, but was in the site "Property Pages", in the Build section.

To open the Property Pages dialog, you can do any of these:

- go to View > Property Pages, or
- go to Debug > [My Site] Properties... (last item in Debug menu), or
- Right-click on the Web Site in the Solution Explorer (2nd item in Solution Explorer, under the solution itself) and choose Property Pages

[image: Menu to launch Property Pages]

Then in the dialog that pops up, click the Build section on the left.  The right side will then contain a drop down box for "Target Framework". When you change it to 4.0, Visual Studio will warn you that the project will be reloaded.  After that, it will debug properly.

[image: Framework setting]

Comment: I had a similar problem in VS 2013. It required a "Clean Solution" followed by a "Build Solution" (not "Rebuild", which I had tried) to prevent the unrecognized targetFramework error from being generated.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem....
I cloned a solution from MS Source safe, open the solution in VS 2015.
Tried to register the dot.net framework 4.0.... nothing worked....
The solution for me:
go to project settings-->Web change the IIS express port http://localhost:59563/ to something like  http://localhost:59569 or check the Override application root URL

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when I used the Visual Studio interfaces to change the .NET version but then reverted the changed files.  To resolve, I closed Visual Studio and deleted the .vs folder from the project.  Visual Studio rebuilds this with the appropriate information when the project is rebuilt.